# Round numbers and divide them to 2 columns

Tags: sed, grep, numbers, rounding

Now it looks like:

```
xmin = 0
xmax = 15.393970521541949
xmin = 15.393970521541949
xmax = 27.58997052154195
xmin = 27.58997052154195
xmax = 46.05797052154195
xmin = 46.05797052154195
xmax = 65.67797052154194
xmin = 65.67797052154194
xmax = 81.08048969617173
xmin = 81.08048969617173
xmax = 82.7959410430839
```

It should look like:

```
0 15.39
15.39 27.59
27.59 46.06
46.06 65.68
     .
     . 
     .
```

Hi I have .txt file from which I filtered only this xmin, xmax numbers with command:

```
sed -n '16,$p' info.txt | grep "xmin\|xmax"
```

I know how to show only numbers but I don't know how to round this numbers and divide them into 2 columns. The result should look like the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk could do it easily:

```
awk '{printf "%.2f%s",$3,!(NR%2)?"\n":FS}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
xmin = 0
xmax = 15.393970521541949
xmin = 15.393970521541949
xmax = 27.58997052154195
xmin = 27.58997052154195
xmax = 46.05797052154195
xmin = 46.05797052154195
xmax = 65.67797052154194
xmin = 65.67797052154194
xmax = 81.08048969617173
xmin = 81.08048969617173
xmax = 82.7959410430839

kent$  awk '{printf "%.2f%s",$3,!(NR%2)?"\n":FS}' f
0.00 15.39
15.39 27.59
27.59 46.06
46.06 65.68
65.68 81.08
81.08 82.80
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf("%.2f ", $NF)} !(NR%2){printf("\n")}' File
```

Print the last field (`$NF`) in each line with format specifier (`%.2f`). Print `newline` after every `second` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    my $mi,$ma;
    while (<>) {
        if (/xmin = ([0-9.]*)/) { $mi=sprintf("%.2f", $1); next; };
        if (/xmax = ([0-9.]*)/) { $ma=sprintf("%.2f", $1); printf "$mi $ma\n" };
    }
```

running this perl script with:

```
    script.pl < data
```

would result in

```
0.00 15.39
15.39 27.59
27.59 46.06
46.06 65.68
65.68 81.08
81.08 82.80
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'N;s/xm.. = //g;s/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]\{2\}\)[0-9]*/\1/g;y/\n/ /' info.txt
```

- read 2 lines
- remove the `xman/xmin =`
- trunc the number
- change new line to space
- cycle

(POSIX version so `--posix` for GNU sed)